# Using Header and BasicHeader with HttpUrlConnection in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

In android 6.0 the `org.apache.http.legacy` library is deprecated, so i try to migrate a project to use `HttpURLConnection`.
In the project, i used the `Header` and the `BasicHeader`. I didn't found how i can replace these classes with `HttpUrlConnection`. I want just to know how can i add a header in a request using `HttpUrlConnection`.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  URL url=new URL("YOURURL");
  HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//establishing connection from url
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");//method type
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");// setting headers
```